# Ubuntu YouTube music player with playlist search and download

Tags: linux, music, ubuntu, youtube

I want to play YouTube music without having to run a web browser.

Requirements:

- Let me enter keywords to search for playlists, and select a playlist to play
- Let me easily download or at least bookmark tracks I like. I have Youtube-dl installed if that can help.
- Does not display video
- Free

Bonus:

- Runs as an Ubuntu indicator
- Open source
- Audio-only YouTube download, to save bandwidth (if possible)

Answer (score 3):

[mps-youtube](https://github.com/np1/mps-youtube) is a console-based youtube player with playlist support. Doesn't display video, great for listening to music. It supports downloading media from youtube (although [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) is much more full-featured regarding downloads).

You may also have a look at [minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube) which is a standalone (graphical) youtube player tring to match a TV-like experience.

Answer (score 2):

**[Olivia](https://snapcraft.io/olivia-test)** is a opensource([**github link**](https://github.com/keshavbhatt/olivia)) online/offline cloud based music player like iTunes, Spotify, Youtube Music etc, Olivia allows you to search any music online stream it, You can set player to save your streams while playback. Olivia lets you create and manage your music Library.

**Install from Ubuntu Snap Store:**

snap install olivia-test

**From Arch User's Repository:**

[pkg-build link](https://aur.archlinux.org/pkgbase/olivia/)

[image: Olivia]

**Features of version 1.0 (revision 63):**

- Allows search music online
- Allows organise music
- Allows download song while streaming
- Allows search YouTube and add result to library
- Plays audio only of YouTube streams (saves data bandwidth)
- Support themes , Dynamic theme based on album art
- Search suggestions
- Player mini mode included , minimal player widget with always on capability and allows set transparency.
- Internet radio, allows play more than 25k online radio stations, list them sort them according to language and country
- Top music chart, allows list top 100 songs country wise
- Beautiful Client side Decoration